# Can I theme the menubar to look different if a window is maximized?

Tags: unity, themes, gtk3, panel, maximized

I know you can theme the Unity menubar in GTK+3 using CSS, but is there a way to theme it differently depending on whether a window is maximized?

This would be useful for e.g. themes where the menubar should appear standalone in the absence of a maximized window, but then seamlessly blend into the top of such a window when there is one.

Preferably, I would like to be able to do this from within the theme files.

Comment: I don't think this is a CSS configurable option.  It seems to me the top bar is probably hard coded since the "top bar transparency" setting toggles on maximize.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible outside of the exit, minimize and maximize buttons. But it may be.