# How to change color of the frame of a maximizing window

Tags: themes, customization, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the “Selected Items” color?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63126/how-do-i-change-the-selected-items-color)
>   [How do I change the theme and window border color?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172280/how-do-i-change-the-theme-and-window-border-color)
>   [Can I theme the menubar to look different if a window is maximized?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184882/can-i-theme-the-menubar-to-look-different-if-a-window-is-maximized)

Though I have read and tried some advises regarding the change of colors in a theme, I found no answer regarding my question, which is:

When I drag a window to the left (or right or up) side of the screen an orange frame shows up, indicating the area that the window will occupy. This frame is in orange.

Can you please inform me how can I change this color to blueish, to match my theme? 
At this point, I would like to inform you that Zorin OS has this blueish frame instead of orange, but I do not know where this color comes from.

Comment: It can be changed in CCSM. The effect you are describing is called window snapping preview.

Comment: I am afraid it does not work. I have already tried that in ccsm.
Snapping windows has nothing to do with color.
I also tried windows appearance but neither this did the trick. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @JorgeCastro It seems this is not a duplicated to that question. The selected color doesn't have an effect on the color showing the transparent box while pushing the window to the edges of screen, AFAIK